# Equivalent docker exec for dockerfile cmd?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The end of my dockerfile looks like this:

```
...

EXPOSE 3000

CMD someapp seed && someapp server
```

For testing purposes I'd like to execute this myself when the container has finished launching so that it doesn't contain the seed data.

What is the equivalent docker exec for this?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking here. If you don't want to run these commands automatically, just drop them from your Dockerfile. Create a new container from your image with a shell (`docker run -it myimage bash`) and then just run them by hand in order to test things.

Answer (score 2):

Scripting `docker exec` usually isn't a best practice: you want your container to be self-sufficient and do as much of its own setup as you can.

One technique that's useful here is to use `ENTRYPOINT` as a wrapper script that does the first-time setup, then ends with `exec "$@"`.  That magic shell line will cause it to run the thing that's named as the `CMD`.

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
# Must be JSON-array syntax; includes the "seed" step
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD someapp server
```

Since the entrypoint is a script, you can do whatever you want in it.  For example, you could make the seeding dependent on an environment variable:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$SKIP_DB_SEED" != "yes" ]; then
    someapp seed
fi

exec "$@"
```

With this construction, you can set the environment variable at startup time to skip the seeding step

```sh
docker run ... -e SKIP_DB_SEED=yes someimage
```

The other thing this lets you do is get an interactive shell in a debugging container, having done all of the first-time startup work.  Any command you put after the image name replaces the `CMD` in the Dockerfile, which in turn appears as the `"$@"` in the script.

```sh
docker run --rm -it someimage bash
```

Comment: Impressive! It goes to show the length some people are willing to go to get what they want. I need to run seed on demand so that defeats automation. I just need the same result as the dockerfile but run it after the machine starts.